# recyclerview reloading items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When I scroll screen, items go invisible, right?
When I scroll back, the items reload. such as, ImageLoader shows "showImageOnLoading".

besides, there was something that completely made me stunned.
i coded like this below:

```
List<String> title;
if (title.get(position).equals("")) {
        holder.textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
      holder.textview.setText(title.get(position));
    }
```

what's interesting was textviews of items were GONE randomly!!!
there is only ONE String is "" in title.
with scrolling textviews being GONE and presenting again....

Comment: visible your `TextView` in else block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because holder keeps item's view. When string is empty you set textview Gone but you has not set visible again. If you want to avoid reload item. You can set setIsRecyclable(false) for holder.

Answer (score 0):

Below line can help:

```
List<String> title;
if (title.get(position).equals("")) {
    holder.textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
   holder.textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   holder.textview.setText(title.get(position));
}
```